# Getting error while connecting Mongodb through Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, ssl, laravel-5

**Getting ssl error while connecting monogoDb from laravel 5.2.**
Added the connection string in config/database.php file.
I used jenssegers/mongodb.

Here is the configuration :

```
 'connections' => [
    'mongodb' => [
        'driver' => 'mongodb',
        'host' => ['hostname'],
        'port' => 'port',
        'database' => 'xxxx',
        'username' => 'xxxx',
        'password' => 'xxxx',
        'options' => [
            'ssl' => 'true',
            'db' => 'xxx'
        ],
        'driver_options' => [
            'context' => stream_context_create([
                'ssl' => [
                   'local_cert' =>  public_path().'/xxx.pem',
                   'cafile' => public_path().'/xxx.pem',
                    'allow_self_signed' => true,
                    'verify_peer' => true,
                    'verify_peer_name' => true,
                    'verify_expiry' => true,
                ]
            ])
        ]
    ]
],
```

And changed default connection in database.php

**'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mongodb')**

Whenever i tried this am getting the response like:**Failed to connect to: Cannot setup SSL, is ext/openssl loaded?.**
openssl and ssl support are enabled in phpinfo().

Is there a way to solve it out?

Thanks